# Searching data for current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is the first query taking less time than the second one in SQL Server?

This query takes 4 seconds to complete:

```
select *
from salesinvmaster
where day(salesdate) = day(getdate()) and
      month(salesdate) = month(getdate()) and
      year(salesdate) = year(getdate())
```

This query takes 10 seconds:

```
select *
from salesinvmaster
where salesdate between '2017-11-01 00:00:00' and '2017-11-01 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the query plans for both queries?

Comment: Looks like you do not have defined an index on the `salesdate`. If you do then the second query should run super fast.

Comment: If you're using datetime, your second query will leave out any rows with 23:59:59 + milliseconds. You should really use `>=` and `<` instead of between.

Answer (score 4):

The two queries are different, because today is some day in December, not November 1st.

My guess is that you do not have an index on the `salesdate` column, and that the first query is returning fewer rows -- hence, it looks faster.  For the record, I would recommend writing the logic as one of the following:

```
where convert(date, salesdate) = convert(date, getdate())

where salesdate >= convert(date, getdate()) and
      salesdate < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, getdate()))
```

Note that SQL Server *does* use an index for the conversion of a date/time value to a date.  This is one of the rare (only?) times when a function does not prevent the use of an index.

As for the second method, it dispenses with the need to include the time component of the values.

Answer (score 3):

Check the Exeuction plan for the query i think We've got implicit conversions on the date!  check this

[image]